# ASP.net MVC Application using Azure OpenID Connect working fine in local but cannot read oid from ClaimsPrincipal.Current refreshing the page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, openid

Thanks in advance for any help you could provide. I've implemented OpenID connect in an ASP.NET MVC application, it's intended to access Microsoft Graph and get the user profile picture for some users loaded from another service.

The front end is build in AngularJS, once the user information is loaded, I'm using the user email to call an ASP.NET MVC method that tries to get the user profile picture from Microsoft Graph. The openid connect implementation is done only in the ASP.NET MVC app, not in Angular.

The error detail generated in

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    encodedPhoto = "ErrorGettingPhoto" + ex.ToString();
}
```

says something like:

> ErrorGettingPhoto System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: generalException
>
> Message: An error occurred sending the request.
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> at Web.Helpers.TokenHelper.GetUsersUniqueId(ClaimsPrincipal user) in F:\AzureAgent\_work\94\s\Helpers\TokenHelper.cs:line 113
> at Web.Helpers.TokenHelper..ctor(ITokenCache tokenCache, HttpContext context, ClaimsPrincipal user) in F:\AzureAgent\_work\94\s\Web\Helpers\TokenHelper.cs:line 33
> at Web.Helpers.GraphHelper.GetAuthenticatedClient\u003eb__10_0\u003ed.MoveNext() in F:\AzureAgent\_work\94\s\Web\Helpers\GraphHelper.cs:line 96

The `StartUp` class has the following structure:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private static string appId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppId"];
    private static string appSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppSecret"];
    private static string redirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:RedirectUri"];
    private static string graphScopes = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppScopes"];
    private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
    private static string loginUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:LoginUrl"];
    private static string authority = string.Format(loginUrl, tenantId);

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
                CookieHttpOnly = true,
                AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, 
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(12),
                SlidingExpiration = false,
                CookieDomain = ".mydomain.com",
                CookieName = ".AspNet.SharedCookie",
                CookiePath = "/"
            });

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = appId,
                    Authority = authority,
                    ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken,
                    Scope = $"openid email profile offline_access {graphScopes}",
                    RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    SaveTokens = true,
                    CookieManager = new SameSiteCookieManager(new SystemWebCookieManager()),
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        NameClaimType = "preferred_username",
                        ValidateIssuer = false
                    },
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                    {
                        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailedAsync,
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync
                    }
                }
            );
        }

        private static Task OnAuthenticationFailedAsync(AuthenticationFailedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage,
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
        {
            notification.HandleResponse();
            
            if (notification.Exception.Message.Contains("IDX21323"))
            {
                notification.OwinContext.Authentication.Challenge();
            }
            else
            {
                string redirect = $"/Error/Error?message={notification.Exception.Message}";
                notification.Response.Redirect(redirect);
            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        private async Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceivedAsync(AuthorizationCodeReceivedNotification notification)
        {
            notification.HandleCodeRedemption();

            var idClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(appId)
                .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
                .WithClientSecret(appSecret)
                .Build();

            var signedInUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity);
            HttpContext.Current.User = signedInUser;

            var tokenStore = new TokenHelper(idClient.UserTokenCache, HttpContext.Current, signedInUser);

            try
            {
                string[] scopes = graphScopes.Split(' ');

                var result = await idClient.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                    scopes, notification.Code)
                    .WithAuthority(authority)
                    .ExecuteAsync();

                var userDetails = await GraphHelper.GetUserDetailsAsync(result.AccessToken);

                tokenStore.SaveUserDetails(userDetails);
                notification.HandleCodeRedemption(null, result.IdToken);
            }
            catch (MsalException)
            {
                notification.HandleResponse();
                notification.Response.Redirect($"/ErrorAccessDenied");
            }
            catch (Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException)
            {
                notification.HandleResponse();
                notification.Response.Redirect($"/ErrorAccessDenied");
            }
        }
    }
```

The TokenHelper has:

```
public class TokenHelper
    {
        private static readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim sessionLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim(LockRecursionPolicy.NoRecursion);

        private HttpContext httpContext = null;
        private string tokenCacheKey = string.Empty;
        private string userCacheKey = string.Empty;

        public TokenHelper(ITokenCache tokenCache, HttpContext context, ClaimsPrincipal user)
        {
            httpContext = context;

            if (tokenCache != null)
            {
                tokenCache.SetBeforeAccess(BeforeAccessNotification);
                tokenCache.SetAfterAccess(AfterAccessNotification);
            }

            var userId = GetUsersUniqueId(user);
            tokenCacheKey = $"{userId}_TokenCache";
            userCacheKey = $"{userId}_UserCache";
        }

        public bool HasData()
        {
            return (httpContext.Session[tokenCacheKey] != null &&
                ((byte[])httpContext.Session[tokenCacheKey]).Length > 0);
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            sessionLock.EnterWriteLock();

            try
            {
                httpContext.Session.Remove(tokenCacheKey);
            }
            finally
            {
                sessionLock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }

        private void BeforeAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
        {
            sessionLock.EnterReadLock();

            try
            {
                // Load the cache from the session
                args.TokenCache.DeserializeMsalV3((byte[])httpContext.Session[tokenCacheKey]);
            }
            finally
            {
                sessionLock.ExitReadLock();
            }
        }

        private void AfterAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
        {
            if (args.HasStateChanged)
            {
                sessionLock.EnterWriteLock();

                try
                {
                    // Store the serialized cache in the session
                    httpContext.Session[tokenCacheKey] = args.TokenCache.SerializeMsalV3();
                }
                finally
                {
                    sessionLock.ExitWriteLock();
                }
            }
        }

        public void SaveUserDetails(UserData user)
        {

            sessionLock.EnterWriteLock();
            httpContext.Session[userCacheKey] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user);
            sessionLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }

        public UserData GetUserDetails()
        {
            sessionLock.EnterReadLock();
            var cachedUser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserData>((string)httpContext.Session[userCacheKey]);
            sessionLock.ExitReadLock();
            return cachedUser;
        }

        public string GetUsersUniqueId(ClaimsPrincipal user)
        {
            // Combine the user's object ID with their tenant ID

            if (user != null)
            {
                var userObjectId = user.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value ??
                    user.FindFirst("oid").Value;

                var userTenantId = user.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value ??
                    user.FindFirst("tid").Value;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userObjectId) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(userTenantId))
                {
                    return $"{userObjectId}.{userTenantId}";
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

The AccountController used from AngularJS to get the profile picture is:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowCrossSiteJson]
        public ActionResult GetProfilePicture(string userEmail)
        {
            return new JsonResult { Data = new { profilePicture = GraphHelper.GetUserPicture(userEmail)}, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet};
        }
    }
```

And the  GraphHelper has the following code:

```
public static class GraphHelper
    {
        private static string appId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppId"];
        private static string appSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppSecret"];
        private static string redirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:RedirectUri"];
        private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
        private static string loginUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:LoginUrl"];
        private static string authority = string.Format(loginUrl, tenantId);
        private static List<string> graphScopes =
            new List<string>(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppScopes"].Split(' '));


        public static async Task<UserData> GetUserDetailsAsync(string accessToken)
        {
            var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
                    {
                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }));

            var user = await graphClient.Me.Request()
                .Select(u => new {
                    u.DisplayName,
                    u.Mail,
                    u.UserPrincipalName,
                    u.Photo
                })
                .GetAsync();

            return new UserData()
            {
                Avatar = null,
                DisplayName = user.DisplayName,
                Email = string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Mail) ?
                    user.UserPrincipalName : user.Mail
            };
        }

        public static byte[] ReadAsBytes(Stream input)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                input.CopyTo(ms);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }

        public static string GetUserPicture(string userEmail)
        {
            string encodedPhoto;
            try
            {
                var graphClient = GetAuthenticatedClient();
                var requestUserPhotoFile = graphClient.Users[userEmail].Photos["64x64"].Content.Request();
                var photoStream = requestUserPhotoFile.GetAsync().Result;
                encodedPhoto = Convert.ToBase64String(ReadAsBytes(photoStream));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                encodedPhoto = "ErrorGettingPhoto" + ex.ToString();
            }

            return encodedPhoto;
        }

        private static GraphServiceClient GetAuthenticatedClient()
        {
            return new GraphServiceClient(
                new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                    async (requestMessage) =>
                    {
                        var idClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(appId)
                            .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
                            .WithClientSecret(appSecret)
                            .Build();

                        var tokenStore = new TokenHelper(idClient.UserTokenCache,
                            HttpContext.Current, ClaimsPrincipal.Current);

                        var userUniqueId = tokenStore.GetUsersUniqueId(ClaimsPrincipal.Current);
                        var account = await idClient.GetAccountAsync(userUniqueId);

                        // By calling this here, the token can be refreshed
                        // if it's expired right before the Graph call is made
                        var result = await idClient.AcquireTokenSilent(graphScopes, account)
                            .ExecuteAsync();

                        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
                    }));
        }
    }
```

The Profile Picture is correctly loaded in local environment, however, when the application is deployed, it works randomly, sometimes the GraphHelper throws an error in TokenHelper in the line

```
var userObjectId = user.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value ??
                    user.FindFirst("oid").Value;
```

If the page is refreshed it works fine again, and continues failing and working randomly.

Tha application is being deployed using Azure Release pipeline, and it's deployed into two OnPrem servers.

I have tried multiple approaches, the following line was added in the StartUp class trying to keep the ClaimsPrincipal.Current property but still sometimes the load of the claims fail.

```
HttpContext.Current.User = signedInUser;
```

Any idea will be very appreciated. The implementation is based in https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-aspnetmvcapp.

Thanks!

Comment: Running multiple instances in the cloud?

Comment: It's running in two OnPrem targets that are part of a ADO Deployment Group. I'm not sure what's the way they're balanced, I'll need to confirm with infrastructure team.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple client applications, then the cookie from one service will not be accepted by the other service. This can be one reason for why you see that random errors when using your service.

For this , you need to [configure the data protection API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Also, the authentication process using OpenID connect can fail if the service instance issuing the initial authentication request is not the same as the one that later received the authorization code. For this you might want to use static routing, for example by IP-address.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Tore Nestenius, the issue was fixed by enabling sticky sessions in the load balancer of the application. It was caused by the fact that the Session was not being shared among the target servers. By using sticky sessions the load balancer guarantees the user requests continue to be processed by the initial target so the session continues to be available. Please refer the following link https://dotnetcodr.com/2013/07/01/web-farms-in-net-and-iis-part-5-session-state-management/